# Why doesn't VCVars.bat find windows.h?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, curl, compilation

I have some old code which is compiled using Visual Studio 2008.

This is launched by our developer environment setup to allow us to compile Curl. For some reason, when I've come to install it on a new dev machine, the Curl compilation doesn't find `windows.h`.

A bit of digging suggests the `VCVars.bat` file finds the following directory:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A

The last SDK version that looks like it's in a structure which includes `windows.h` is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A

If I take a copy of `VCVars.bat` and modify it to manually set the `WindowsSdkDir` environment variable, I can get the compilation to work. This all feels rather hacky though.

Is there a correct way to fix this?

**Edit** - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK) suggests the later directories are installed from Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I suppose it all depends on how you installed your SDKs

Comment: Well we have Visual Studio 2008, 2012 and 2013 installed with the latest service packs which is where the SDKs are installed from (i.e. none manually).

Comment: MSDN is a very good resource.  Don't use Wikipedia.

Comment: [Setting the Path and Environment Variables for Command-Line Builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx).

Comment: `vsvars32.bat` is the file we're calling but as I said, it's finding the 8.1A directory which doesn't have `Windows.h` in it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If the 8.1A directory doesn't contain Windows.h at all then your installation is broken. However the file is located in a different place in the 8.x versions of the Windows SDK than previous versions, so you probably just didn't look hard enough. You should find it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\include\um`.

Comment: I don't have an include directory within 8.1A - does that suggest my Visual studio 2013 installation is corrupt?